# The call getOAuthToken returns null value - what am I missing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to use a file picker in Apps Script, and I've tried the sample code from the
[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) but its not working - the ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() call is returning null.

I've followed all the instructions to change to a Standard Cloud Project and enabled the Google Picker API, but its just not happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns it was actually the call DriveApp.getRootFolder() that was failing in the function provided in the sample code:

```
function getOAuthToken() {
    try {
        DriveApp.getRootFolder();
        return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    } catch (e) {
        // TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
        Logger.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
    }
}
```

While the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) works correctly without this call, I discovered the reason for the error was that I needed to enable the Google Drive API after switching to a Standard Cloud Project (required to run the Google Picker API).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).